# If $n$ is pseudoprime and $[n,a]=[n,a+1]=1$, then $(a+1)^n\equiv a^n +1 \pmod n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've found a problem ($[a,b]$ is the gcd of $a,b$.)

> If $n$ is pseudoprime, and $a$ an integer such that $[n,a]=[n,a+1]=1$, show that
>
> $$(a+1)^n\equiv a^n +1 \pmod n$$
>
> Suggestion: $a^n\equiv a\pmod n, \; (a+1)^n\equiv a+1\pmod n$.

I recognize the suggestions as Fermat's little theorem but that is true when $n$ is prime. I tried to make some tables on Mathematica but the identities do not seem to hold. Is this true or am I making some mistake?

Comment: See my edits for standard MathJax or LaTeX usage. Note that with `\pmod 7` you see $\pmod 7,$ and with `\pmod 73` you see $\pmod 73,$ and with `\pmod{73}` you see $\pmod{73}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I tried to use `\mod` but it gives a weird whitespace. I thought my browser had a bug with LaTeX or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime) states,

> Pseudoprimes are classified according to which property of primes they satisfy.

Your question problem doesn't explicitly state which particular property is being used for $n$, but the property seems (e.g., based on their suggestion) to be [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime). If so, the phrase "If $n$ is pseudoprime, ..." is supposed to mean "If $n$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $a$ and base $a + 1$, ...".

Their suggestion would then be true since $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \implies a^n \equiv a \pmod{n}$ and $(a + 1)^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \implies (a + 1)^n \equiv a + 1 \pmod{n}$. From this, substituting $a^n$ for $a$ on the right side in the second congruence gives what is requested, i.e., $(a + 1)^n \equiv a^n + 1 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: Oh, I spotted the mistake. In the book I'm reading, I guess that the author confused something and wrote that pseudoprimes are nonprime $n$ such that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. Although this is a valid test, I guess he meant the pseudoprime definition you mentioned because now everything fits perfectly.